# Is it possible to get the hardening exponent and coefficient (n, k) if I just know the yield point, the ultimate stress, and the failure strain?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

For a certain steel I have the following data:

- Yield stress and strain (engineering)
- Ultimate tensile strength (engineering), I don't have the strain at this point
- Strain at failure (engineering), I don't have the stress at this point.

I want to recreate the true stress-strain curve, maybe using the hardening exponent and coefficient.
Is this data enough? Or will I need more?